# Wackerly's proof of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: statistics

In Wackerly's "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" 7th edition page 378 they give a proof of the CLT which uses Taylor's theorem:

> By Taylor’s theorem, with remainder (see your Calculus II text)
>   $$m_{Z_1} (t) = m_{Z_1} (0) + m^{'}_{Z_1} (0)t + m^{''}_{Z_1} (ξ )t^2 /2,$$ 
>   where $0 < ξ < t,$
>   and because $m_{Z_1}{(0)} = E(e^0 Z_1 ) = E(1) = 1,$ and $m^{'}_{Z_1}(0) = E(Z_1) = 0,$
>   $m_{Z_1} (t) = 1 +m^{''}_{Z_1}(ξ ) / 2t^2,$ where $0 < ξ < t.$

What is the purpose of the "$\xi$" symbol, as $m^{''}_{Z_1}(0) =E(Z_1^2)=V(Z_1)=1$ 
so $\mu_n(t) = [1+(t^2/2)/n]^n?$

Comment: It's the Lagrange remainder. There is no real need to use the symbol $\xi$, it's just some number between $0$ and $t$.

Comment: I have tried to put your Question into TeX. Please check that I have not changed the meaning.